# iOS 9 can't open UIWebView anymore

Tags: uiwebview, ios9, afnetworking-2

since iOS 9 my app can't open a web page containing both javascript and xml anymore. I think I read everything is around on the internet but it seems I can't figure out what's happening.
The server running the php is:
- tls 1.2 compliant;
- forward secrecy compliant;
- certificated as Apple describes.

The app is using AFNetworking 2.6 (version 3.0 should be available at the end of October) and the error that I got is:

NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

when I call:
`[self.mainWebView loadHTMLString:string2 baseURL:baseURL];`

I also tried to manage exceptions in the plist as Apple describes (NSAllowsArbitraryLoads) or writing my domain name (NSExceptionDomains) but nothing changes.

Any ideas where should I investigate more?

Thanx so much for your help.

Fab

Comment: I forgot to mention that the certificate is self signed.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your `.plist` file.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: I've already added that code in the plist but it doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx to Apple Technical Support I fixed the problem. Once I verified with TLSTools that the server was correctly configured solution was to send our self signed certified via e-mail, then tapping on it in Mail, the app started to work fine.